# Can I migrate a existing zend-project to a symfony-based without starting up from the scratch?

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, migration

is there a possibility to move a zend 2.0 -based project into a symfony-based?
Maybe there is a chance for a more or less simple migration?

Thanks in advance.

Philipp

Comment: Well php code stands php code. Depending on how your code is coupled, you will be able to do copy/paste of certain classes to your new project. But that's all. There wasn't a tool to migrate from Symfony1 to Symfony2, so from Zend to Symfony4 ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply no. Unfortunately Symfony4 and Zend2 doesn't have an interoperability. They are using different configuration, routing / controller, database interaction and view layer. Also Zend components and Symfony components are not interoperable and compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by wrapping symfony arround your existing application, and do a progressive migration to symfony, components by components without lost any exisiting functionnalities of your application.

This is quite well described in this post :

https://stovepipe.systems/post/migrating-your-project-to-symfony